# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't see mapped drives

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-10, drive-mapping

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 1803 64-bit. I have a mapped drive (H:) and when I try to run an SSIS package that depends on finding files in that drive, it tells me the files can't be found. If I change the code to use a UNC path, it works fine. However, in this case I'd really prefer using the mapped drive. It allows me to map a drive on my local PC for testing purposes, and then use the same drive letter on the production PC.

I've also noticed that if I try to open a project in VS 2017 in the same environment, but type in e.g., F: as the path, it doesn't recognize it, even though F: is a mapped drive on my computer.

I'm not running VS in Admin mode. What could be causing this?

Comment: You may need to apply a registry fix for Mapped drives. I apply it to all Win 10 machines. See my question [(along with my answer to my own question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71796183/cannot-register-com-assembly-during-build) .

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work for me. The value for EnableLinkedConnections should literally be "dword:00000001", correct? This isn't some shorthand value I've never seen before?

Comment: @Melanie: It's a DWORD with value 1. The answer should include this: reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLinkedConnections /t REG_QWORD /d 1