# Cannot register COM assembly during BUILD

Tags: visual-studio

I have several Programs that are COM dlls. I am setting up my development environment on a new computer. When I build some DLLs they build successfully. Others do not build successfully.

[Cannot Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkfHK.png)

I have tried opening visual studio with "run as administrator". However when I do this on this new computer, I cannot see the mapped drives.

[Mapped Drives missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K840f.png)

Staying with Cannot register, I notice in the image that the project that will not build references a URL in the error message. The project that builds successfully references a mapped drive.

For troubleshooting I would like to replace the URL with the mapped drive. I opened the project (opened .vbproj, not .sln) that does not build by navigating to the mapped drive but still when it was built, the URL appears in the Error window.

How do I get the mapped drive to be used during Build rather than the URL? Where can I change that reference?

Not knowing if my troubleshooting idea above will work, let me ask the more general question. How do I eliminate the Cannot register error?

The best solution for me would be to have the mapped drives appear when I select "run as administrator". I know this is possible because on a different computer at different location with a different IT staff, the mapped drives appear. How do I get the mapped drives to appear when I "run as administrator"

Thank you,
pat

The image to my comment regarding the Registry fix.
[Fix Mapped links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0VqO.png)

Comment: My IT guy found the solution to the Mapped drives not appearing when starting Visual Studio with "Run as Administrator". There is a registry fix we have been running for years. I forgot about it. I am including an image of the code rather than the code itself. Since this code changes the registry, I am not sure if posting the text or .reg file would violate any community standards. So to be safe you can view the image and decide if this works for you.

Comment: No need to hide it in an image. reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLinkedConnections /t REG_QWORD /d 1